# Rookie to MS ACCESS - hyperlinking to folder of PDFS?

Tags: ms-access, pdf, hyperlink

I am 2 days old to ms-access, I have made a basic table and search form (shown below)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Ck9.jpg)

Each value in the 'Grid' field I wanted to link to a pdf of the same name, eg 5928.pdf in a folder automatically - I have 7800 records so to do it manually would take forever.

At the moment the hyperlink does nothing when I click on it - is there a rookie friendly (easy) way to automatically link the grid field to the pdf of the same name in my folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the `Click` event of the Grid textbox control.

Set the folder where the files are being stored and then build the file path from the item that was clicked.

```
Private Const FilesFolder As String = "D:\Some folder\"
Private Const FileExtension As String = ".pdf"

Private Sub Grid_Click()

    Dim filename As String
    filename = FilesFolder & Me![Grid] & FileExtension

    'Validate file path and Open
    If Len(Dir(filename)) > 0 Then Application.FollowHyperlink filename

End Sub
```

MSDN: [Application.FollowHyperlink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-followhyperlink-method-access)

Comment: Hi Kostas, that worked - thank you very much ! Just one question, when the pdf opens it doesnt open infront of the Access table but behind it, is there a simple way to make it appear ontop when the pdf opens rather than in the background?